# 'splice' instead of 'filter'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a field for entering tags. It is also possible to remove tags.
And here I have a question.

My deletion code is below. Tags can be deleted one at a time, in any order (first, last, somewhere in the middle, it doesn't matter).

```
 const deleteTag = (index) => {
      setTags((prevState) => prevState.filter((tag, i) => i !== index));
    };
```

But I would like to use 'splice' instead of 'filter'. With the same functionality.
Tell me how to do it

Comment: Why do you want to use splice instead of filter? Why not [read how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)? (hint: they're not directly interchangeable)

Comment: [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is an in-place operation, doesn't make sense to use it in this scenario

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, but splice performs actions faster than filter. Can't they be replaced with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splice's first argument is the item index, and the second argument is how many items you want to delete from that index.

```
const deleteTag = (index) => {
  setTags((prevState) => {
    prevState.splice(index, 1)
    return [...prevState]
   });
 };
```

***UPDATE***

If you are using `<StrictMode>` the setState will execute twice and will delete two items instead of one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is a small nuance. In your case, if I remove the tags from the end, then everything works fine. But if I delete the first tag, or from the middle, then two tags are deleted (the one I delete and the next one). Can this be fixed somehow.

Comment: This shouldn't be happen except if the deleteTag function executed twice. ( this will not happen with the filter method whatever deleteTag method is executed )

Comment: Can it be because, slice is in place, and as you delete any element before the last, say 0th index, it deletes it and the one at index 1 become the 0 index. But the iterator skips to 1st index, which is actually the one at index 2. And so you delete one and skip another. So you lose two elements when you return new array[...]

Comment: @Mina I added the code where I call this function, maybe it will help solve the problem

Comment: In fact the setState which called twice, and that because <StrictMode> component ( which wrap <App> component ), StrictMode is executed every setState twice to ensure to not mutate original state. To make it only execute once and just comment <StrictMode> and it will work fine. ( I encourage you to use filter instead of splice and keep StrictMode ) but if insist to use splice just delete <StrictMode>

Comment: I updated my answer, and I just made a demo with your condition.
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-ellis-y0983j?file=/src/index.js:220-232

Comment: @Mina Yes, your code works correctly without <StrictMode>. But what should I do in my case?

Comment: I think it would be better to use the filter as it is a safe method Whatever it is executed will not change the result.

Comment: @Mina I don't use <StrictMode> in my code

Comment: Also, if you insist to use a splice you can use this code for deleteTag method.

Comment: const deleteTag = (index, tag) => {
    const newTags = [...tags]
    newTags.splice(index, 1)
    setTags(newTags);
  };

Comment: @Mina In your example you are doing another copy of prevState. Also, setTags is prop, not state. Therefore we have another affect.  Can you help me fix the code given this information?